# Using quotes in SublimeText build system command

Tags: applescript, sublimetext

I'd like to execute a simple AppleScript command as part of a Sublime Text build system. I created a `sublime-build` file where the command is

```
"cmd": ["osascript", "-e", """tell application "Preview" to activate"""]
```

but I can't seem to escape the quotes properly. I've tried using `\"`, `\'`, and a few other combinations, with no luck. Does anyone know what the proper syntax is? In the shell, I simply write

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Preview" to activate'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I got it. The solution is simple and I must have missed it:

```
"cmd": ["osascript", "-e", "tell application \"Preview\" to activate"]
```